# Start windows service as admin in wix installer

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have created a windows service, which adds and modify the registry key values. Wix installs and start service successfully, but the action which modifies the registry key  are not taken place, when I manually start service as admin account, then service works perfectly. When I goto start > administrative tools > services and right click on my service then on properties and then on logon tab, gave account and password of admin then service runs and add , modify registry values successfully. But if I install it using wix installer, it install and start succesfully, but service can't modify registry key values, May be it needs administrator privilege when starting to work correctly.

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" AdminImage="yes" InstallPrivileges="elevated" />

<Component Id ="MyServiceInstaller" Guid="{35FB6173-9484-48CA-BA86-30B0A68B301D}">
    <File Id="MyNewService.exe" Name="MyNewService.exe" Source="MyNewService.exe" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1"/>
    <ServiceInstall
      Id="ServiceInstaller"
      Type="ownProcess"
      Vital="yes"
      Name="abcService"
      DisplayName="abc Service"
      Description="Monitoring and management service "
      Start="auto"
      Account="LocalMachine"
      ErrorControl="ignore"
      Interactive="no">
      </ServiceInstall>
    <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="AbcService" Wait="yes" />
  </Component>
```

Guide me please,
Thanx.

Comment: Is Administration a valid windows username that is part of the Administrators group?  Have you tried also entering the password in the ServiceInstall xml?

Comment: In an ideal world the service would report somewhere the reason it can't update the registry. Assuming it's actually that Admninistration account, it's not going to work unless a password is supplied. I'd expect the service to fail startup during the install if it's credentials are incorrect, which is presumably why you go and add the password manually.

Comment: @PhilDW Administrator was incorrect, question is modified actual value is LocalMachine, what service is doing, is that it is adding and modifying the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\ key, when I set credentials in the service properties it modifies the key otherwise it does not modifies the keys, is there any option in wix or in service so that I should not give credentials manually. thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Is the service running as LocalSystem? (You write LocalMachine - to my knowledge this isn't a valid account). Are you trying to write to HKCU or HKLM? The details are a bit unclear here. Are you working on [proxy settings](https://serverfault.com/questions/34940/how-do-i-configure-proxy-settings-for-local-system) or something?

I don't think LocalSystem has access to HKCU, but it should be able to write anywhere in HKLM. I suppose you should [impersonate the user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that's required.

**From MSDN**: "...A service that runs in the context of the LocalSystem account inherits the security context of the SCM. The user SID is created from the SECURITY_LOCAL_SYSTEM_RID value. The account is not associated with any logged-on user account. The registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER is associated with **the default user, not the current user**. To access another user's profile, impersonate the user, then access HKEY_CURRENT_USER."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run with local system account and access HKCU settings. It doesn't work like that. Which user's HKCU  setting, given that there may be dozens on a machin?e It works when you run it with the actual user's credentials because then there is an actual user with an actual HKCU registry key. Services do not run in a particular user's context unless you run them with that user's credentials. You'd need to figure out the SID for the user before you can figure out the registry hive for that user.

Comment: Thank you, what I am doing now, is iterating through all the user sid's and changing IE proxy setting registry key for all users, what I need is to change the key for currently logged in user, is there any way to get currently logged in SID through windows service, if I try to get through service code it gives S-1-5-18 instead of something like this S-1-5-21-2199884586-3455549055-2692760295-1000 and I dont know about user credentials since it is going to install to many pcs. Guide me please.